# Remove element from XML with ElementTree in python

Tags: python, xml

I have a .tmx file, and I want to extract the text from the seg tag, however because of the inside tags such as bpt and ept, I cannot extract this text. So I would like to remove the bpt tag completely.
I tried .remove() method. However, this also removes the text.

I cannot use BeautifulSoup because my original file is .tmx

Comment: Can you use lxml ? The extension file is not a problem, as with lxml you can parse xml contained in a string. It is usually better to use a well-tested and very used library than write your own code.

Comment: @Wind56 I updated my explanation

Comment: Ok thanks, I will look your issue when i have more time. Also consider posting an issue to inform the maintainers that there is some issues with encoding if you are sure of what you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ElementTree does not keep parent references in the XML tree. That's inconvenient but not the end of the world.

But in order to delete any node in an XML document, you need to delete it from its parent, so you need a way to get the parent node.

Easiest for ElementTree is to iterate all potential parents and then check each parent if it has a child you want to delete.

Assuming `<bpt>` is always a child of `<seg>`, that would mean iterating the `<seg>` elements:

```py
for node in root.iter('seg'):
    prev = None
    for child in list(node):
        if child.tag == 'bpt':
            # retain child node's tail, if any
            if child.tail is not None:
                if prev is None:
                    node.text = (node.text if node.text else '') + child.tail 
                else:
                    prev.tail = (prev.tail if prev.tail else '') + child.tail
            node.remove(child)
        else:
            prev = child
```

If `<bpt>` could be *anywhere*, changing the above to `for node in root.iter():` iterates all nodes.

**Explanation**

ElementTree sub-divides the document tree in a very proprietary manner. One main drawback is that there are no "parent" references - relative navigation between nodes is very limited in general - another is that there are no text nodes.

Instead of being a stand-alone node, any text after an element (i.e. text directly following the closing `</tag>`) becomes a property of that element, called [`.tail`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.tail):

```
<!-- <bpt> elements and their "tails" -->

<seg><bpt i="1">{\\f3 </bpt>Cover page <ept i="1">}</ept><bpt i="2">{\\f2 </bpt>U1 - Insert graphic<ept i="2">}</ept></seg>
<!-- -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^                  -----------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     -->
```

Consequently, if we remove the `<bpt>` element, the `tail` is lost, too. In order to save it, we must add the content to the preceding element's `tail` (as with *"U1 - Insert graphic"*, which now belongs to the `<ept>`), or if there is no preceding element, to the parent element's `text` (as with *"Cover page "*, which now belongs to the `<seg>`):

```
<!-- <bpt> elements removed, "tails" moved one to the front -->

<seg>Cover page <ept i="1">}</ept>U1 - Insert graphic<ept i="2">}</ept></seg>
<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     -->
```

Repeating the same removal process with `<ept>` would lead to the follwing - all "tails" are now merged into `<seg>`'s text:

```
<seg>Cover page U1 - Insert graphic</seg>
<!-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   -->
```

Comment: @StarryNight See updated code, explanation follows.

Comment: Yes it fixed the error. But now it does not delete the second bpt tag in the .tmx file. It does delete it in the string tho. :(

Comment: @StarryNight It removes the second `<bpt>` node for me. Look closely, your code must be different.

Comment: I think is the same. I uploaded the code and the result above. Thank you again for still being here and trying to help :)

Comment: I tried for node in root.iter(): as well. It gives me the same result :(

Comment: @StarryNight With your XML, copied from your question, I get the following result `<seg>Cover page <ept i="1">}</ept>U1 - Insert graphic<ept i="2">}</ept></seg>`. All the `<bpt>` nodes are gone, all the text is retained. The `<ept>` nodes could be removed in the same way, then `<seg>Cover page U1 - Insert graphic</seg>` remains. It works, that's all I can say. Give me XML where it doesn't work.

Comment: @StarryNight ""Yes it fixed the error. But now it does not delete the second bpt tag in the .tmx file. It does delete it in the string tho. :( ""

Seems to be an issue with the way you open the file or the encoding, either way I do not think the code given is in cause, try putting your file into a string, verify that it is equal to this one. It will probably not be.

Comment: @StarryNight I have one suspicion that I'd like to rule out - could you try again with `for child in list(node):` instead of `for child in node:`?